# prevent multiple database access (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have a database which contains data of events that should be run:

Event 1 - 01:00am

Event 2 - 02:00am

Event 3 - 03:00am

These events get triggered under certain conditions if a user reloads a page (e.g. if he reloads the page at 04:00am all events are triggered)

What happens, if Player 1 and Player 2 simultaneously reload the page at 04:00am:

Both fetch these events from the database.

Both run these events.

=> events are doubled.

Of course, as soon as the event is done, it gets deleted, but as long as the script hasn't finished the event, it stays in the database and other players will run them as well if they reload their page.

Is there a way to prevent this by e.g. saying to SQL "Hey, please block ids 1, 2 and 3 from selecting"?

Comment: Are the events triggered by time or by a page load?  If by time, then schedule them in the database.  If by page load, then do you want to run them once or twice when two users load a page within a given amount of time?  This seems like arcane rules for running code.  Usually, the rules do not depend both on time and user actions.

Comment: When you start processing the event, mark it in database as "used"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The events have a time when they should run. But they can only run if a user reloads the page. Thus, they are triggered by time and page load.
@ cxminer hm, possible. But wouldn't this decrease performance quite a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of locking mechanism to do what you want.  Here is one mechanism, using a log table of times when the job ran.

The *first* thing a job does would be to insert a record into the table saying that it is running.

The *second* thing a job does is check to see if there are any other jobs currently running that started earlier than this job.  If so, then it deletes or updates its job record, so nothing is running.

The *last* thing a job does is update/delete its record to say it is not running.

These actions will act as a locking mechanism.

The "earlier than this job" part of the logic should eliminate race conditions -- assuming there are no ties on the timing.  You can use an auto-incremented id for this purpose as well.

Note:  this can run into problems when jobs fail.  This can be due to the job itself or due to the server going down.  If you know that the run time is always less than 10 minutes (or so), you can incorporate this logic into the checks.

Comment: thanks, but I don't quite understand step 2. What do you mean with race conditions? Shouldn't it be enough to only insert an "I'm running" record into the database?

Comment: @Akeno . . . Race conditions occur when two pages load "at the same time".  You want to be sure that one -- and exactly one -- job runs.  Both could insert records saying they are running, check, find another job running, and neither would run.  Race conditions and locking loops are what make event-driven programming hard.